# iOS 6 Project gives @synthesize error when deployment changed to iOS 5.0

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

When i ran my iOS 6 Project on an older xCode using iOS 5.0. It issues warning and fire exception on executing project.

```
Property 'window' requires method 'window' to be defined - use @synthesize , @dynamic or provide a method implementation
```

what is the science behind it ? why do i need to explicitly add @synthesize in 5.0. while it works fine in iOS 6.

Comment: Because it wasn't until 6.0 that Apple made synthesis automatic. (Using iOS 6 as more of a timestamp. rmaddy is right about this being a compiler feature.)

Comment: This has **absolutely nothing** to do with Xcode.

Comment: i never said it has something to do with xcode. i repeatedly mentioned iOS 5.0 & iOS 6.0

Comment: Should i mannualy insert @synthesize to run the project using sdk 5.0 ? or there is a better option.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Actually, this is a result of the latest compiler, not iOS 6.0.

Comment: Automatic property synthesis is feature that came with Xcode 4.4, see [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html), so it is a compiler feature, not an iOS feature.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right, and your answer has my up vote. I was merely using iOS 6 for simplicity because the question was about the diff between iOS 5/6. However, for accuracy I added the parenthetical addition to my comment.

Comment: @0x7fffffff The difference is important because with the latest compiler I can use these features on a project that runs under iOS 4.3 or later, not just iOS 6.0.

Comment: @rmaddy Great point, that one somehow completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with iOS 6 or iOS 5. This has to do with the version of the compiler used in Xcode. The latest versions of the compiler, used in the latest version of Xcode, support many new features not found in older versions of the Objective-C compiler. One of those features is no longer needing an explicit `@synthesize` statement. Once you take advantage of these newer features, you can't use an older version of the compiler to compile your code.

So now the question becomes - why are you trying to build this project in an older version of Xcode? What is your goal? Why not use the latest Xcode and simply change the project's Deployment Target to iOS 5.0 and leave the Base SDK as "latest".

Comment: Well i have the old mac os 10.7.2 Hackintosh, updating hackintosh is too much hassle. and i can't install xcode 4.5 on my mac OS.

Comment: How did you create an iOS 6 project without Xcode 4.5? Anyway, if you must use an older Xcode, then you lose iOS 6 and you must update your code to work with the older compiler. This means putting in the @synthesize statements and fixing any other modern Objective-C syntax you may be using.

Comment: i didn't create the project. i got it from someone else who has xcode 4.5. thanks anyway

Comment: @Faizan What do you mean by "thanks anyway"? I answered your question. I explained what is causing the problem and I told you how to fix it.

Comment: thanks for the help i really appreciate it. dont' get me wrong .

Comment: No problem. I'm glad i could help. Enjoy.